# Code prints the address' of the array values and not the values?

Tags: arrays, c, printf

Why is this code printing the addresses of the int array and not the values?
Say `str` is "Aug 18, 2002", it prints this:

```
total digits: 6 all digits list: 49 56 50 48 48 50
```

When I want it to say:

```
total digits: 6 all digits list: 1 8 2 0 0 2
```

Heres the relevant parts of the code.

Function:

```
int extractDigits (char str[MAX], int digitsInInputString[MAX]) { //returns total digits in str, and appends digitsInInput to list of digits
        int i;
        int totalDigits = 0;

        for (i=0; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++) {
                if (isdigit(str[i])) {
                        digitsInInputString[totalDigits] = str[i];
                        totalDigits++;
                }
        }

        return totalDigits;
}
```

Main program:

```
        digitsInString = extractDigits(myStr, strNums);
        printf("total digits: %d all digits list:", digitsInString);
        for (i=0; i<digitsInString; i++) {
                printf(" %d", strNums[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
```

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't use [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) with `char`s. Do `isdigit((unsigned char)str[i])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite this line `digitsInInputString[totalDigits] = str[I];` to be:

```
digitsInInputString[totalDigits] = str[I] - '0';
```

This will convert from ASCII characters to decimal.